# What should I look for when when i get the error "runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'node' (aka 'struct node')"?

Tags: c

```
bool check(const char *word)
{


    node* node_ptr = first;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(word); i <= len; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] == '\0')
        {
            if (node_ptr->is_word == true)
            return true;
            else
            return false;
        }

        int index = get_index(word[i]);
        if (node_ptr->children[index] == NULL)
            return false;

        node_ptr = node_ptr->children[index];

    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the code line in question or atleast where the error msg is pointing me.

I never had this error before so I`m having alot of difficulties dealing with it. 
A google search wasnt really helpfull either.

Comment: Post definition of `first`.  Even better post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that the pointer variable node_ptr is null but you're trying to access a field inside the structure that is expected to be at the memory location, but the memory location is invalid (the pointer is not initialized to a valid value). You either need to make sure your code doesn't have a mistake that makes it end up with a null pointer as the process goes along, or you need to have it point to a valid memory location by setting it to a memory allocated the memory using new (if you're using C++) or malloc (which you can use in C or C++).  It's also not clear what the variable "first" is here...that's probably part of the problem... hope this helps!